# Xamarin.Forms 4.1 Android Frame Renderer changing backgroundColor

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 4.1. 
Crashed on Android in Frame Renderer when `BackgroundColor` is changed.

My FrameRenderer in Android is as follows:

```cs
public class NewFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    private Context localcontext;
    string propertychange = "";

    public NewFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        localcontext = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

    public override void SetBackgroundColor(Color color)
    {
    }

    public override void Draw(ACanvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
        DrawOutline(canvas, canvas.Width, canvas.Height, Element.CornerRadius);
        base.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor(hexbackgroundcolorframe));
    }

    private void DrawBackground(ACanvas canvas, int width, int height, float cornerRadius, bool pressed)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint
        {
            AntiAlias = true
        };
        Path path = new Path();
        Path.Direction direction = Path.Direction.Cw;
        Paint.Style style = Paint.Style.Fill;
        using (RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height))
        {
            float rx = localcontext.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
            float ry = localcontext.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
            path.AddRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, direction);
            paint.SetStyle(style);
            paint.Color = Color.ParseColor(hexbackgroundcolorframe);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }

    private void DrawOutline(ACanvas canvas, int width, int height, float cornerRadius)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint
        {
            AntiAlias = true
        };
        Path path = new Path();
        Path.Direction direction = Path.Direction.Cw;
        Paint.Style style = Paint.Style.Stroke;
        using (RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height))
        {
            float rx = localcontext.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
            float ry = localcontext.ToPixels(cornerRadius);
            path.AddRoundRect(rect, rx, ry, direction);
            paint.StrokeWidth = 5f;
            paint.SetStyle(style);
            paint.Color = Color.ParseColor(hexoutlinecolorframe);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception that you get? Without it, we would be speculating!

Comment: could you show your complete framerender codes?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after I removed this function.

public override void SetBackgroundColor(Color color)